# Datatable delete link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can create and edit a record in a datatable with jQuery.  I am having trouble deleting a record. Here is my code.  Thanks for the help.

```
   // New record
   $('a.editor_create').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      editor.create(
          'Create new record', {
          "label": "Add",
          "fn": function () {
              editor.submit()
          }
      });
  });

  // Edit record
  $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      editor.edit(
      $(this).parents('tr')[0],
          'Edit record', {
          "label": "Update",
          "fn": function () {
              editor.submit()
          }
      });
  });
  $('#example').dataTable({
      "sDom": "Tfrtip",
          "sAjaxSource": "browsers1.json",
          "aoColumns": [{
          "mData": "sn"
      }, {
          "mData": "reg_name"
      }, {
          "mData": "audit_name"
      }, {
          "mData": "audit_data"
      }, {
          "mData": "minor",
          "sClass": "center"
      }, {
          "mData": "major",
          "sClass": "center"
      }, {
          "mData": null,
              "sClass": "center",
              "sDefaultContent": '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a>'
      }]
  });
```

Comment: What other libraries and plugins are you using?

Comment: I have edited your title to remove the tags based on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles which says generally that they should be included there.

Comment: Please show code related to "trouble deleting a record." - what have you tried? also,  `editor.submit()` should have a semi-colon